# Why do I have to compile as elf and not binary when calling my C functions while developing a bootloader?

Tags: assembly, x86, bootloader

I'm trying to learn how to develop a bootloader. There is a part I don't understand.
I can write my code in assembly, compile it with nasm, and simulate it in a virtual box.
But when it comes to writing and compiling the kernel in C, I can't understand it.
Why do we compile with i386-elf-gcc and not gcc?
Why do we compile our assembly code with -f elf32 instead of -f bin?
Aren't ELF linux's executables?
Shouldn't our kernel or bootloader be binary as raw code?
Why elf?

When I compile my assembly code as elf, when I open the hex file and look at it, it is not found in bytes 511-512 of the bootloader signature. So the bootloader signature  is carrying the from the first sector. How come the BIOS loads when the bootloader signature is not in the first sector.

boot.asm

```
bits 16
extern _kmain ; this is in the c file

start:

    call _kmain

    cli  ; stop interrupts
    hlt ; halt the CPU

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xAA55
```

kernel.c

```
typedef unsigned char uint8;
typedef unsigned short uint16;
typedef unsigned int uint32;


#define VGA_ADDRESS 0xB8000
#define BUFSIZE 2200

uint16* vga_buffer;

#define NULL 0

enum vga_color {
    BLACK,
    BLUE,
    GREEN,
    CYAN,
    RED,
    MAGENTA,
    BROWN,
    GREY,
    DARK_GREY,
    BRIGHT_BLUE,
    BRIGHT_GREEN,
    BRIGHT_CYAN,
    BRIGHT_RED,
    BRIGHT_MAGENTA,
    YELLOW,
    WHITE,
};

uint16 vga_entry(unsigned char ch, uint8 fore_color, uint8 back_color) 
{
  uint16 ax = 0;
  uint8 ah = 0, al = 0;

  ah = back_color;
  ah <<= 4;
  ah |= fore_color;
  ax = ah;
  ax <<= 8;
  al = ch;
  ax |= al;

  return ax;
}

//clear video buffer array
void clear_vga_buffer(uint16 **buffer, uint8 fore_color, uint8 back_color)
{
  uint32 i;
  for(i = 0; i < BUFSIZE; i++){
    (*buffer)[i] = vga_entry(NULL, fore_color, back_color);
  }
}

//initialize vga buffer
void init_vga(uint8 fore_color, uint8 back_color)
{
  vga_buffer = (uint16*)VGA_ADDRESS;  //point vga_buffer pointer to VGA_ADDRESS 
  clear_vga_buffer(&vga_buffer, fore_color, back_color);  //clear buffer
}

void kmain()
{
  //first init vga with fore & back colors
  init_vga(WHITE, BLACK);

  //assign each ASCII character to video buffer
  //you can change colors here
  vga_buffer[0] = vga_entry('H', WHITE, BLACK);
  vga_buffer[1] = vga_entry('e', WHITE, BLACK);
  vga_buffer[2] = vga_entry('l', WHITE, BLACK);
  vga_buffer[3] = vga_entry('l', WHITE, BLACK);
  vga_buffer[4] = vga_entry('o', WHITE, BLACK);
  vga_buffer[5] = vga_entry(' ', WHITE, BLACK);
  vga_buffer[6] = vga_entry('W', WHITE, BLACK);
  vga_buffer[7] = vga_entry('o', WHITE, BLACK);
  vga_buffer[8] = vga_entry('r', WHITE, BLACK);
  vga_buffer[9] = vga_entry('l', WHITE, BLACK);
  vga_buffer[10] = vga_entry('d', WHITE, BLACK);
}
```

linker.ld

```
ENTRY(start)
OUTPUT_FORMAT("binary")
SECTIONS {
    . = 0x7c00;
    .text :
    {
        *(.boot)
        *(.text)
    }
    .rodata :
    {
        *(.rodata)
    }
    .data :
    {
        *(.data)
    }
    .bss :
    {
        *(.bss)
    }
}
```

Commands:

```
gcc -m32 -c kernel.c -o build/kernel.o -std=gnu99 -ffreestanding -O2 -Wall -Wextra
nasm boot.asm -f elf32 -o build/boot.o
ld -m elf_i386 -T linker.ld -o build/kernel.bin build/kernel.o build/boot.o
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: ELF is a file format for object and executable files, holding important meta data such as symbol tables and section information.  A linker can link multiple ELF objects into one ELF binary.  This is not possible with a raw binary.  As a final step, the ELF file may be turned into such a raw binary if needed.

Comment: I still can't understand the issue. This is how the bootloader loads the kernel. Ok, it's switching from real mode to protected mode, then calls the kernel. But why is it compiling with elf? Shouldn't the entire program be binary for the processor to understand? For example, how is windows compiled? Elf or binary? Or something else?

Comment: Note the plain "gcc" is also not producing raw binary. It may very well be an alias/symlink to your `i386-elf-gcc` (or the 64 bit version thereof).

Comment: @ali: It is still binary code. ELF is a file format with sections, one of which is called `text`, which is the actual machine code.

Comment: I updated the question, can you take a look again?

Comment: @ali ELF is only used to be able to link the various objects into a single executable.  This executable can then be converted into a raw binary or loaded as an ELF file.  You cannot link raw binaries as they do not have any meta data; some sort of container is needed.

Comment: See the `OUTPUT_FORMAT("binary")` directive in the linker script?  That instructions the linker to create a raw binary.

Comment: Your code doesn't work because your boot code is likely being placed after the kernel because you don't have a `.boot` section in the NASM code and because you processed kernel.o before boot.o when linking. You also need to put the processor in 32-bit protected mode before calling your kernel. You can't run your 32-bit code in 16-bit real mode.

Comment: So how do I compile and link these codes?

Comment: You can convert ELF to binary with `objcopy`

Comment: Your C uses at least one global variable, `uint16* vga_buffer;`.  But your asm doesn't set up segment registers before calling the compiled C.  It also doesn't switch to 32-bit mode, but you compiled your C with `gcc -m32` not `-m16`.  If you single-stepped your code (after getting it to link and run), you'd see it executing crazy instructions from decoding machine code bytes in the wrong mode.

Comment: I'm also unsure how this would link without unresolved errors since you are using ELF and are using `_kmain` in the assembly code. In Windows and OS/X there is a needed underscore, but not in Linux using ELF. Your C function is called `kmain` so you should be using `kmain` in your assembly code.

Comment: The other thing here is that even if you add `section .boot` to the top of your assembly file (the bootloader itself); initialize appropriate registers;  add the code to the bootloader to enter protected mode; call the kernel; there is one other important thing - the way the linker script is written (and how they intended it to be used) the kernel will be loaded after the bootloader (in effect at 0x7e00). You will have to load the kernel into memory yourself. The BIOS only reads the first sector of the drive (the first 512 bytes). After that you have to load the rest manually.

Comment: I defined the GDT table. I switched to 32 mods. But how do I know the location of the kernel in my combined binary file?